# Use php variable in google pie chart

Tags: javascript, php, google-pie-chart

I want to use my PHP variable in Google chart,but the chart couldn't read my PHP tag. As you can see the code below I put my PHP variable in the script. (The PHP variable I have defined at top of the code and the result is correct). What's wrong with my code ? Is there any solution for this ? Do ask me for more information if needed. Thank you.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Order', 'Amount'],
      ['Completed',     '<?php echo$completed ?>'],
      ['New',      '<?php echo$new ?>']
    ]); 

    var options = {
      title: 'Total Order ' + <?php echo$total; ?>
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What is the rendered code? Any errors in the console?

Comment: No, because the chart doesn't show up. But if I change the php variable in the script to Integer, the Google chart works perfectly. @chris85

Comment: Not the chart, the source code. Is the page blank? I'd also put spaces between the `echo` and variable but that should break it.

Comment: Only the div for the Chart is blank, other element in the page is all fine. @chris85

Comment: The generated JS is blank?

Comment: yes, it show nothing in the div @chris85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Example.

```
<?php 
$completed = 50;
$new = 10;
$total = 30;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Load the AJAX API-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">


            google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            function drawChart() {

                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    ['Order', 'Amount'],
                        ['Completed', parseInt('<?php echo $completed; ?>')],
                        ['New',       parseInt('<?php echo $new; ?>')]
                ]); 

                var options = {
                    title: 'Total Order ' + <?php echo$total; ?>
                };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="piechart"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format), for Google visualization pie charts, there must be one datatype `string` column and one `number` column.

So you should parse the `Amount` column to `integer` or `float` before rendering the data. You can do it in php itself or in javascript as,

```
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Order', 'Amount'],
      ['Completed', parseInt('<?php echo $completed; ?>')],
      ['New',       parseInt('<?php echo $new; ?>')]
    ]); 

    var options = {
      title: 'Total Order ' +  parseInt('<?php echo $total; ?>')
    };
```

You can also use javascript `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` if your amount values containing decimal values.

Answer (score 0):

```
<span id="json-genderby"><?php echo json_encode($arrayGenderGroupBy); ?></span>

<div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(window).on('load', function() {
        google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var json_gender = $("#json-genderby").text()
            
            var arrayGenderBy = [];
            var count = 0;

            $.each(JSON.parse(json_gender), function(i, item) {
                if (count == 0)
                    arrayGenderBy[count] = [item[0], item[1]];
                else 
                    arrayGenderBy[count] = [ item[0], parseInt(item[1]) ];
                count ++
            });
            

            var data    = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayGenderBy);

            var options = { title: 'Servey Questions Answered by Gender' };
            var chart   = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use scripts in PHP.

But, You can't use PHP in scripts.

It won't work.